# What are the differences between bundle and package in (La)Tex?

Tags: packages

When reading some articles and answers, I sometimes see the terms ***bundle*** and ***package***. Could someone explain what they are and the difference/relationship between them?

Comment: A bundle is a collection of packges, more or less.

Comment: @Johannes_B So does it means a collection of _any_ packages or just a few _specific_ packages? And is there any general guide to tell people **how/when** to make a bundle instead of just one big package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

package has specific meaning in latex as in

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

so `longtable` is a package and `article.cls` or "latex itself" are not packages.

But in ctan and texlive and linux distributions there are usually "package managers" that handle software distribution. For them, a "package" is a related collection of software and documentation that is installed together.

Usually you can distinguish from context what is meant by "package" but when you can't some people loosely refer to a related set of latex files as a "bundle" instead.

Recently the l3build system formalised that usage using `bundle` to mean a set of related things that are handled by the build script, but the usage of "bundle" to mean a collection of packages is older than that.